# smarty Error: Syntax Error in template

Tags: php, smarty

i have a session which is set thrugh php but when i try to get data using smarty i get following error

```
Error: Syntax Error in template "d:\server\theme\menu_inc.tpl" on line 10 "{if $smarty.session.user-permissions-ses.t_mgt == 1}" - Unexpected "."
```

smarty template code.

```
{if $smarty.session.user-permissions-ses.t_mgt == 1}
    information here
{/if}
```

I can't seem to know what might be causing this error.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the hyphens, neither PHP nor smarty like to allow them in variables.

This should make it work though:

```
{if $smarty.session.{"user-permissions-ses"}.t_mgt == 1}
    information here
{/if}
```

[Here](http://www.smarty.net/forums/viewtopic.php?t=18856) is a thread on the Smarty forums with a little more information.